# r, does not equal, nas are not included

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter my data to leave out certain values.  The problem is that I want to include the NAs.  When I use the does not equal, "!=", operator, the NAs are also removed.

```
    a= c("A","C","B",NA,"C","A",NA,"B","A")
    df = data.frame(a)

    df2 <- df %>%
       filter(a != "B")
    df2
```

For example, I would like df2 to include everything not equal to B (A and C) and NA instead of only A and C.

Comment: Thank you @bouncyball - Are the NAs being left out because they are treated as a special value in R and are always registered as false when using !=?

Comment: They are always treated as `NA` when using `!=`. You can test for yourself with, e.g., `1 != NA` or see the help at `?NA`.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor.  That makes sense.  The != only keeps "TRUE" values, but NAs shows up as NA and are getting dropped.

Comment: @bouncyball - if you wanted to write up your comment as an answer, I would select it as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: An `NA` might be interpreted as something like [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), where the `NA` means the actual value could be anything but is unclear due to potentially a problem (e.g., insufficient `factor` levels, missing set membership). With this `c("A", NA, "B")` could signify "any letter". Testing equality with `a != "B"` gives a logical `NA` because where `a` is `NA`, it could be `"B"` (meaning `FALSE`) or something else (meaning `TRUE`). Perhaps I'm over-thinking it, but `NA` to me means "could be any of the legitimate values".

Comment: sounds about right to me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can include another condition in the `filter` function which will keep the `NA` values:

```
df %>%
   filter(a != "B" | is.na(a))

#      a
# 1    A
# 2    C
# 3 <NA>
# 4    C
# 5    A
# 6 <NA>
# 7    A
```

From [`?NA`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html)

> Logical computations treat `NA` as a missing `TRUE/FALSE value...

There's more to the explanation, but you can consult the help file.

Answer (score 5):

`NA` is never equal to anything.

```
NA == NA # NA, not TRUE
```

@bouncyball's would be the recommended solution, if you want to check if two values or variables are really the same you can use `identical` :

```
df %>% filter(!sapply(a, identical, "B"))
```

or using library `purrr`

```
df %>% filter(!map_lgl(a, identical, "B"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this additional information.  bouncyball's solution works best for the current need, but this will be very helpful in the future.