# dplyr not filtering dates correctly

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data structure, it looks as such in the `dput` form:

```
test_df <- structure(list(dob = structure(c(-25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, 
                                            -25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, -25932, 
                                            -25932, -25932, -16955, -13514, -12968, -12419, -12237, -11537, 
                                            -10168, -9742, -9376, -9131, -8766, -8676, -8462, -8189, -8036,
                                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           -45L))
```

This should produce a variable with 45 rows.

If I then run:

`test_include <- test_df %>% filter(dob == '1899-01-01')`

This returns the proper amount of rows, which would be 14.

But if I do the opposite of this and filter for all rows that DO NOT equal '1899-01-01' it returns a weird result:

`test_exclude <- test_df %>% filter(dob != '1899-01-01')`

Instead of returning 31 rows (45 - 14), it returns 15 rows, which makes no sense.

Does anyone have a solution and explanation as to why it is doing this?

Comment: You have NAs. Those don't get past either filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `!=` does not get `NA`, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773751/r-does-not-equal-nas-are-not-included) for more information, but here is an example with your data

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

> test_df %>% filter(dob == ymd('1899-01-01')) %>% nrow()
[1] 14

> test_df %>% filter(dob != ymd('1899-01-01')) %>% nrow()
[1] 15

> test_df %>% filter(is.na(dob)) %>% nrow()
[1] 16

> test_df %>% filter(dob != ymd('1899-01-01') | is.na(dob)) %>% nrow()
[1] 31
```